# i want to get topic or main word in a sentence

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I had worked on LDA and genism model.They give the prediction of top keywords in a documents.Suppose i had text test file in csv that have 10k sentences .I want top key word as there heading for each and every sentence in a row how we can do it (topics/target  are not pre defined)

Comment: Can you elaborate more or give some examples? What I understood is you have the keywords list from the document. And you want to show the sentence specific keyword, title(heading) of each sentence?

Comment: Yes you got it Right.Is there is any way in which we can get top keyword for every sentence ?

Comment: One way is searching each keyword in a sentence and checking their frequency. If found you can store in a temporary list and after completion show them `top keyowrd` as a heading.